# How to copy a list before POST/GET block execution?

Tags: angularjs, http-post

I am trying to copy a list that is present in POST body just before the execution of POST block.

Below is the code snippet:

```
app.controller('OneClickController',function($scope,$http){

  $scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions ={};
  $scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.contactDtlsWrapper.contactDtls = {};
  $scope.invest = {};

        $scope.submitOneClick = function(investDtls) {
        //$scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.contactDtlsWrapper.contactDtls.emailAddr = angular.copy('mbc@gmail.com');
        //$scope.invest = angular.copy(investDtls);
        $scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions = angular.copy(investDtls);
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/investor/api/v1/oneclick',
            data : $scope.oneClick
        }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.out= response;
        alert("Success " +  $scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.listInvestOptions[0].investName);
        }); 
        }
});
```

Here list **investDtls** is getting copied into **listInvestOptions**.

But problem is ,the controller is not called that means

```
 $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/investor/api/v1/oneclick',
            data : $scope.oneClick
        })
```

above block is not executing at all where as I can check the copied values in the alert statement which I am printing inside the success block.

At the same time if I am copying a normal string value like:

```
$scope.oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.contactDtlsWrapper.contactDtls.emailAddr = angular.copy('mbc@gmail.com');
```

It is getting copied and the controller is called also ,inside which I can check the updated **emailAddr** value.

I can not see any errors in the console also.

Most importantly, if I am copying a temp list that is not part of the POST body,
copy is successful and the controller is also called.

```
$scope.invest = angular.copy(investDtls);
```

Any help most welcome.

Comment: Can you add in the error callback to the $http call and check if there is an error in there somewhere? Is it possible that the investDtls object is malformed?

Comment: @ Praval 'Shaun' Tirubeni

As I have mentioned above, success callback is called(alert method is executing which is inside success callback) so I think there will be no use of error callback.
Anyway I have tried by adding Error callback below success callback.